# Is it possible/advisable to use Reactive Programming when you can't control the Publisher

Tags: rxjs, rx-java, reactive-programming, reactive-streams

I am very new to Reactive Programming using ReactiveX Libraries, even so, I have already started appreciating its fluent APIs and style of programming that avoids a class of concurrency bugs.

Therefore, I would like to use ReactiveX (specifically RxJava and RxJS) at work, where I am developing an application that essentially receives a "stream" of updates from a server and displays it to the user (after some manipulations). The way I see it, in terms of reactive-streams nomenclature, my application is a "Subscriber" that subscribes to a Publisher to receive values of interest.

I have a few doubts though that are preventing me from using RxJava at work:

1. The "Publisher" in my case is another service (that does not use RxJava or such) that I do not control or maintain, therefore, I cannot change its code to implement "Publisher" interface. As such, is it even possible (or, at least, not un-idiomatic) for me to use RxJava? If so, would I have to create a wrapper of sorts to implement a Publisher that takes values from this other service and emits it?
2. Is it possible/common for the Subscriber and Publisher to be implemented different languages, like the Subscriber (written using RxJS) subscribes to a Publisher written using RxJava?

Comment: How is this "publisher" implemented? Is it over the network? Retrofit is one way to consume and expose a http source as a reactive publisher, but it is one-shot. For streaming, you can look at RSocket but it requires the server side to support it as well. RxJS doesn't support the reactive streams approach.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The "publisher" in my case is an ActiveMQ messaging server. As far as I understand (I'm still new to the project), it uses JMS standard for message passing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The short answer

Shouldn't be a problem. Reactive programming isn't concerned with data formats or publishers at the level of a network. It's entirely possible to have only a small bit of functionality be reactive without impacting the rest of your codebase at all.

JavaScript and Java both let you switch between reactive and imperative styles with minimal fuss.

Just like it doesn't matter what language a server or a client is running so long as they can both read and send well-formed messages. Reactive libraries are generally entirely self-contained.

#### The longer answer

From a client's point of view, what your server is doing can be abstracted in many ways. What's simplest/best has a lot more to do with your networking libraries than the server. An angular app (for example) can treat any and all network traffic as streams using Angular's HttpClient. It doesn't matter what the server is doing, nor how it sends packets. Angular can pass them on as streams.

---

Even if it's not built-in, it should be relatively easy to layer reactive libraries on top of whatever else exists.

Subjects are the building block that let you seamlessly switch between reactive/functional styles and imperative styles of programming.

However you're receiving data currently, you can create a subject and use its `.next` to pass that data into a stream.

```js
public payloadData: Subject;

function processData(payload){
  this.payloadData.next(payload);
}
```

Then you're on your way. You can build out your reactive framework from there.

```js
/***
 * An observable, that (once subscribed) begins to keep a timestamped array of all
 * values emitted by payloadData.
 *
 * TODO: Remove stale data and write it to disk.
 ***/
function accumulateDataHistory(): Observable {
  return this.payloadData.pipe(
    timestamp(),
    scan((acc, curr) => ([...acc, curr]), []),
    shareReplay(1)
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The examples indeed helps. After doing some digging I realized that the server (or publisher) that emits the data in my case uses ActiveMQ and passes them using the JMS protocol. From your example, I'd say that it should be possible to have a wrapper that receives these plain updates, transforms them into a stream, and emits them. I'm not sure yet if it gives more benefits than a fluent API that I can chain methods to.